# How to seperate integer values using sscanf in c?

Tags: c, linux

I have a string which captures details stored in `data`

`User 6%, System 18%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%`

What i am doing is

`sscanf(data,"User %d,System %d,IOW %d,IRQ %d",&user,&sys,&iow,&irq);`

I am getting wrong output . why ?
Is is like i am missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You left out the `%` symbols and some spaces - try:

```
sscanf(data,"User %d%%, System %d%%, IOW %d%%, IRQ %d%%",&user,&sys,&iow,&irq);
```

Answer (score -2):

You have wrong output because you input string is like:
`User 6%, System 18%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%`

But you try to scan a string like:
`User 6, System 18, IOW 0, IRQ 0`